# How can I temporarily bypass a water heater?

Tags: water-heater

Is there a way I can keep my water turned on and bypass my water heater so I can have water in my home? It's a 30 gallon electric water heater... I can't get a water heater until next week..

Comment: Are you trying to get water out of the hot side of faucets (that's obviously not hot) or did you turn off the water to your house?

Comment: Sounds like you have an open pipe that would normally feed the water heater?  If so. putting either a cap, or better, a shutoff valve, on it would do the trick.

Comment: Yes I did turn off the breaker and I did turn off the water from outside coming inside I did find the pipes that run to the water heater outside and it does already have like a cut off valve but will that still let my water run through the house if I cut that one off and turn the main one back on

Answer (score 3):

If you expect to need to rework the plumbing for the new heater anyway, just cut off both the supply and outlet pipes and slip on a Sharkbite hose. They're not particularly inexpensive, but it'll make quick work of the temporary fix.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Whatever you do, you might as well turn off the breaker for the water heater and leave it off, if you haven't already done so.

I assume you have a leak in the water heater and you've turned off the water at the main.

If someone had the foresight to put a shutoff valve on the supply for the hot water heater, all you have to do is close that valve, and you can turn your water back on.  (If there's not, you probably ought to install a shutoff valve for the water heater supply wen you replace the unit.)

If that's not the case, you can cap the supply at the heater.  (If you're not sure which is the supply - cap them both.)  This may be very easy or a little bit of a chore.

If there is a length of flexible hose between the pipe and the water heater it will be very easy, just unscrew the fittings and insert the plugs with a little teflon tape on the threads.  Suitable plugs should be available at a plumbing supply house.  If you're not sure how to identify the right plug, the best bet would probably be to take pictures and measurements with you to the supply house.

If the pipe goes all the way to the fitting, with the fitting disconnected, you may or may not have enough play to lift the pipe a couple inches and get the plug in there.  If you don't have any play, you'll have to move the water heater, or cut the pipes.

If you want to move the water heater, you'll have to drain it first, and even then it may be a bit awkward and heavy, but once it's out of the way you will have access to the threaded fittings on the ends of the pipes and can plug them easily.  If you can't move it, you can always cut off the pipes.

Cutting the pipes with a pipe / tubing cutter is very easy.  You'll want to cut the pipes just a few inches above the fittings so you have plenty of pipe left to work with after the fact and you can push them aside and cap them easily.  (Rather than installing a plug in the fitting, you'll have to install a cap on the cut pipe.)

You can solder on a cap, or use a push on cap like a Sharkbite to cap the pipe.  When you're installing the new water heater, along with adding a shutoff valve, you can install flexible hoses on the pipes so the process is easier in the future.

If you simply cap the pipes at the water heater, you'll no longer have to deal with the leak, but you'll have no water at the hot water outlets in the house, only at the cold water outlets, which is usually fine.  You could temporarily bypass the heater connect the cold water supply pipe to the hot water out pipe - but I doubt you'll want to do that, it will be more trouble for no practical purpose I can think of.

Comment: Yes I did turn off the breaker and I did turn off the water from outside coming inside I did find the pipes that run to the water heater outside and it does already have like a cut off valve but will that still let my water run through the house if I cut that one off and turn the main one back on

Comment: @TammyMumford - you want to follow the cold water supply pipe back from the water heater.  If you get to a valve before you get to any T's or branches, that will shut off the supply to the water heater and nothing else.  If you close that valve, you should be able to turn your main shutoff back on, without any more water getting to the water heater and leaking.